# End date not earlier than Start date and datepicker format

Tags: jquery, datepicker

if i remove dateformat, End date will hide earlier date from Start Date..

The problem is, i have to change the date format to dd-mm-yy while make sure End date datepicker are disable to choose earlier date from Start Date

```
        $("#StartDate").datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
            numberOfMonths: 1,
            onSelect: function (selected) {
                var dt = new Date(selected);
                dt.setDate(dt.getDate() + 1);
                $("#EndDate").datepicker("option", "minDate", dt);
            },

        });
        $("#EndDate").datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
            numberOfMonths: 1,
            onSelect: function (selected) {
                var dt = new Date(selected);
                dt.setDate(dt.getDate() - 1);
                $("#StartDate").datepicker("option", "maxDate", dt);
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$("#StartDate").datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
            numberOfMonths: 1,
            onSelect: function (selected) {
                minDate = $("#StartDate").datepicker("getDate");
                var mDate = new Date(minDate.setDate(minDate.getDate()));
                $("#EndDate").datepicker("option", "minDate", mDate);
            }
        });
```

You will also have to additional work: 
1. On page load only enable #StartDate textbox and disable #EndDate textbox 
2. When #StartDate textbox is removed of value, clear value of #EndDate textbox and disable #EndDate textbox